# Adding media icon to text editor. How?

Tags: media

I've enabled the Media editor and would like an Add Media icon to be available in my text editor (CKeditor). How would I enable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you also have wysiwyg module installed. You can go to admin-config- ckeditor there you can choose for different editor types like full-html which buttons are availible. To upload images i like to use the kcfinder module.

Comment: Thanks @Frogger

I don't have wysiwyg but instead Ckeditor and IMCE. So CKeditor isn't compatible with the media icon?

Comment: Wysiwyg module is very handy and makes installing and integration of ckeditor and IMCE easier. But no harm done you can configurate the integration of IMCE in ckeditor from Admin->Settings->ckeditor profile->File browser settings->IMCE integration